# PostgreSQL get unique data from two tables in multi-column unique

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables as follows:
Get all the days in the table1 if they are not in the table2. Based on id and day. (time is not important, day is important).

```
   create table table1 (tableRes_id int,
   colDate1 TIMESTAMP,
   unique (tableRes_id,
   colDate1));
  
   insert
       into
       table1
   values 
   (1,'2023-03-01 19:02:11.000'),
   (1,'2023-03-02 12:29:01.000'),
   (2,'2023-03-01 16:01:25.000'),
   (1,'2023-03-03 12:41:56.000'),
```

```
   create table table2 (tableRes_id int,
   colDate2 TIMESTAMP,
   unique (tableRes_id,
   colDate2));
 
   insert
       into
       table2
   values 
   (1,'2023-03-02 12:29:01.000'),
   (2,'2023-03-01 16:01:25.000');
```

```
   create table tableRes (id int,
   val text,
   code text);
   
   insert
       into
       tableRes
   values 
   (1,'val1','4qw544w'),
   (2, 'val2',' fd87rr'),
   (3, 'val3',' asd8d78'),
   (4, 'val4',' qe9547fd');
```

How can I have the following results:

```
|1|val1|2023-03-01 19:02:11.000|
-------------------------------
|1|val1|2023-03-03 12:41:56.000|
```

[Check online](https://dbfiddle.uk/_dt67MJz)

Answer (score 4):

Though you have not explicitly specified; From your table structure I understand;

```
tableRes.id = table1.tableRes_id;
```

> Get all the days in the table1 if they are not in the table2

So, we have to use a left join between table1 and table2.

I created your tables in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0c7e/1) and wrote a query which works.

```
select t1.tableRes_id, t3.val, t1.colDate1
from table1 t1
join tableRes t3 on t1.tableRes_id = t3.id
left join table2 t2 on t1.tableRes_id = t2.tableRes_id 
and t1.colDate1 = t2.colDate2
where t2.tableRes_id is null;
```

This gives me expected output :

```
tableres_id       val          coldate1
1                 val1         2023-03-01 19:02:11:000
1                 val1         2023-03-03 12:41:56:000
```